# Is it prohibited to buy new things or do any construction work when anyone at home is pregnant?

Tags: pregnancy

Is it prohibited to buy new things like clothes, vehicles etc or do any construction work (even tiny construction work) when anyone at home is pregnant?

What do scriptures say about it?

Comment: Welcome back Mr. Green!